# How to count number of weeks and days of week any month

Tags: php, algorithm

How to count number of weeks and days of week any month.

Comment: i want no. of weeks of any month for example in this date jan-01-2011 6 weeks.any idea ?

Comment: What is the first day of the week and what is the last?  You will need to adjust any algorithm given to account for some calenders starting on Sunday and others starting on Monday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I think I got you:

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1, 2011);

$week_day = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2011));

$weeks = ceil(($days + $week_day) / 7);

echo $weeks;
```

Comment: Although many years ago, this one helped me build a perfectly working 'show-Human-Date' php function. From a datetime field into: seconds, minutes, hrs, days, weeks, months and years. Your cal_days_in_month did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Some date are incorrect with this formular.  Such as: 2020-feb return 6 expect 5 2009-feb return 5 expect 4, 2012-jun return 6 expect 5, 2014-may  return 6 expect 5.

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with my question, but if you are building a calendar 1 week at a time.  E.G. you are showing the user a single week at a time, date("N") is needed as a mod against using mktime() when using weeks because it accounts for the day of the week the year starts on.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This code returns the number of days, weeks of a month.

```
<?php
for ($year = 2011; $year <= 2012; $year++){
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++){
        $num_of_days = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
        $month_Year = date("F",mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
        echo "<b>$month_Year, $year </b><BR>";
        echo "Number of days = $num_of_days <BR>";
        $firstdayname = date("D", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
        $firstday = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
        $lastday = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
        $lastdayname = date("D", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $lastday, $year));
        echo "First day of the month = $firstday,$firstdayname <BR> ";
        echo "Last day of the month = $lastday,$lastdayname <BR> ";
        $no_of_weeks = 1;
        $count_weeks = 0;
        while($no_of_weeks <= ($lastday+$firstday)){
            $no_of_weeks += 7;
            $count_weeks++;
        }
        echo "Number Of weeks = $count_weeks <br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to figure where does $lastday and $firstday come from?

Comment: Ohh ! I had previously written code to find out the first and last day of month also. Forgot to remove it.

Comment: The code, honestly, is pretty awful. Too much mktimes and dates, when all that could be written in one statement with explode - `list($var, $var2, ..) = explode("-", date("X-X-X-X-...", mktime(0,0,0,$Month,$day,$year));` my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on "what is the starting day of a week?"

Let's say our first day of a week is Monday, means if there are 5 Mondays in a month, we will have a month with 5 weeks.

```
function nbweeks_of_month($month, $year){
    $nb_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $first_day = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));

    if($first_day > 1 && $first_day < 6){ 
        // month started on Tuesday-Friday, no chance of having 5 weeks
        return 4;
    } else if($nb_days == 31) return 5;
    else if($nb_days == 30) return ($first_day == 0 || $first_day == 1)? 5:4;
    else if($nb_days == 29) return $first_day == 1? 5:4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function weeks($month, $year){
        $num_of_days = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); 
        $lastday = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); 
        $no_of_weeks = 0; 
        $count_weeks = 0; 
        while($no_of_weeks < $lastday){ 
            $no_of_weeks += 7; 
            $count_weeks++; 
        } 
    return $count_weeks;
} 

echo weeks(2,2011)."<br/>";
echo weeks(9,2012)."<br/>";

?>
```